# Upgrading AngularJS app to an hybrid Angular-1.6 / Angular-4 kills the perf

Tags: angularjs, angular, angular2-upgrade, angular-upgrade

I've just updated my AngularJS 1.6 app by following the [Angular 4 upgrade guide](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/upgrade.html). Basically I've added new angular 4 dependencies in `package.json`, bootstrapped the app via `UpgradeModule` and created a new simple component in angular 4. Everything works as expected but the performance is really bad!

The application is a dashboard application with potentially lots of widget components and lots of http requests to the backend to fill each widget content.

Depending on the dashboard, the upgraded app is 2x to 5x slower to load and display the dashboard, and chrome network console shows the http requests are run in a sequence instead of being shot all at once like in the 1.6 version. Overall, the UI is also a lot less fluid.

I've played with `ngZone` and tried to run requests outside of angular `zone.runOutsideAngular(() => { ... })` to reduce refresh cost due to change detection. The result is slightly faster but still far slower than the original 1.6 only version.

Is there something to consider when upgrading to an hybrid 1.6-4 app to keep great original performance? Thanks!

Comment: As a test, I created a very basic AngularJS 1.4 sample app and used UpgradeModule (@angular/upgrade/static) to bootstrap it using Angular 4. There is a very obvious "flash of unstyled content" for {{}} interpolation of AngularJS scope objects, which makes me rather concerned about performance.

Comment: Please ignore my previous comment regarding performance. When I bootstrapped an actual, existing AngularJS 1.4 app using Angular 4 UpgradeModule, performance seems fine (it even seems ... snappier?). I'm using @angular/upgrade 4.0.3.

Comment: @Adrien Chauve did you find a solution in the end?

Answer (score 3):

We are using hybrid application. According to our measures NG2 adds about 20% to the initial NG1 time. It not so bad, but we did a lot of staff after just configuring hybrid:
1) - Bundles instead of multiply requests for NG2 (thanks CLI)
2) - AOT for prod; JIT for dev
3) - Tree-shaking
4) - Conditional poly-fills (modern browsers don't require any poly-fills, but they are necessary for old browsers)

We are trying to integrate the following staff as well:
1) - Lazy loading. But I am not sure if it is working for hybrid applications
2) - Web Worker to move NG2 to a separate thread. But again I am still not sure if it is working for hybrid applications
3) - Some custom detect changes strategies

[Here](https://github.com/mgechev/angular-performance-checklist) is a good checklist regarding NG2 performance. I hope it will help you.

Comment: Thank you for the link on ng2 perf recap, it's interesting. But in my case I really just bootstrapped the app with angular 2+ but the rest of the code is still the same (full angular 1.6), and the perf problem really starts once the app is loaded and starts running (i.e. it loads my dashboard object and then each widget of the dashboard handles its requests to get the data to display).

Answer (score 2):

I have hybrid app Ng1.5+Ng2.4.0. I also had performance problems with angular4 in hybrid mode by 2 reasons.

1. This relates to DEBUG only since ng4 performs extra checks. In production mode (call `enableProdMode()` before bootstrap to turn it on) angular4 even a bit faster than ng2.

   `import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';`

   `enableProdMode ();`
2. Ng4 in hybrid mode schedules digest if any watch expression function in angularjs made async call. I.e. if you use lodash `throttle` function in angularjs watch expression to reduce digest rate then having Ng4 can lead to opposite effect -- digests will queue as snowball.